# FastAPI does not throw exception

Tags: python, fastapi

I continue writing my first project on the FastAPI. My final method is delete. It deletes record. But after deleting record i post the same "delete" request and the FastAPI says that it was deleted instead of throwing the exception. I checked version_instance and it is None. I checked db and there is no such version. You can post any query parameters and the status code will be 204. So I'm confused. Has somebody any ideas about it?

main.py:

```
@app.delete('/', status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
async def delete_config(service: str, version: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    service_instance = db.query(models.Service).filter(
        models.Service.name == service
    ).first()
    if service_instance is None:
        return HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Service not found')
    version_instance = db.query(models.ServiceVersion).filter(
        models.ServiceVersion.service_id == service_instance.id
    ).filter(models.ServiceVersion.version == version).first()
    print(version_instance)
    if version_instance is None:
        return HTTPException(
            status_code=400, detail='Version of service not found'
        )
    if version_instance.is_used == True:
        return HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Config is in use')
    db.query(models.ServiceKey).filter(
        models.ServiceKey.service_id == service_instance.id
    ).filter(models.ServiceKey.version_id == version_instance.id).delete()
    db.query(models.ServiceVersion).filter(
        models.ServiceVersion.service_id == service_instance.id
    ).filter(models.ServiceVersion.version == version).delete()
    db.commit()
    return 'deleted'
```

Comment: So what does `print(version_instance)` show? What is the value of `version_instance` if `is None` doesn't trigger?

Comment: print(version_instance) shows that I definitely know what is in version_instance variable. I edited my post to make everything clear. Shortly, there are configs that are stored in db in my project. Each service can have mulltiple versions of configuration. You can delete only versions of config with the flag in_use = False. Each version of config consists of multiple key-value pairs. So when we decide to delete some config we should make sure if it exists and if it is in use. version_instance is used to find records in ServiceKey table be version_instance.id and to delete them.

Comment: And as I said print(version_instance) shows None.

Comment: You're returning the HTTPException - I'm guessing you meant to `raise` it? (and if it still doesn't change, the next step is to check if your `if version_instance` check is _actually_ triggered (I'm guessing it is, and the missing raise is the issue).

Comment: Hm, I thought I'd checked it. But you're right again. Thank you